# Infinite finitely splitting tree and AC

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

The problem is: Using the Axiom of Choice, prove that if $(X,\leq)$ is an infinite finitely splitting tree, then $(X,\leq)$ has an infinite path. Be explicit where you use the Axiom of Choice.

I have a solution I'm not entirely sure about:

Call the minimal element of the tree $x_0$ (it exists by definition of tree). Then, the set of immediate successors of $x_0$ is finite and nonempty by definition of finitely splitting tree. Call it $A_0$.

Then define the function $g$ that selects one (any) of the elements of $A_0$, and call it $x_1$, i.e. $g(A_0)=x_1\in A_0$.

Repeat the process, consider $A_n$ the set of immediate successors of $x_n$ (finite and nonempty), and assign $g(A_n)=x_{n+1}\in A_n$ (with $x_{n+1}$ any element of $A_n$).

Therefore, we have a system of sets $S=\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty} A_i$ (note it is infinite), and a choice function (**which exists by the Axiom of Choice**) since $g(A_i)\in A_i\ \forall i$, and $A_i\neq \varnothing \ \forall i$, since we are considering a finitely splitting tree.

Hence, we get a sequence $(x_n)$ for $n<\omega$ which is infinite because $S$ is, and $g(S)=(x_n)$, and $x_{n+1}$ is an immediate successor of $x_n$ for all $n<\omega$, thus $(x_n)$ is an infinite path.

Are there any problems in this proof? My doubts reside in that I am defining the choice function $g$ (which I know that exists by AC) on the system $S$, which I think also has to be defined using the AC, but for that you need $g$ again... Maybe is there a way of defining $S$ without mentioning $g$, and then construct $g$ on $S$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very common misconception is that you are *defining* the choice function. You cannot, should not, and do not. You are trying to define *an infinite path* (also known as a branch).

What you need to do is first fix a choice function which chooses a successor of a node in the tree, then use recursion to define this branch by iterating this choice function (and prove, of course, that it is an infinite branch).

Do note, sometimes "finitely splitting" includes the situation that not every node splits, in which case you need to argue that you can make your choice in a way that is still generating an infinite path, and not getting stuck at some point.

Comment: I don't really get the argument. For the minimal element, you can choose a successor (without AC), and then how would you iterate? How do you fix such a choice function? Also, I don't get how you would get stuck. If the node doesn't split, then the choice function chooses the only immediate successor and continues, right?

Comment: (1) You let the choice function choose the successor. You can choose any *one* point without AC, yes, but you need to choose infinitely many times, in succession. How do you do that without already assuming a branch exists and you just following that? (2) You fix it the same way you fixed the successor of the root, by saying "I know there is at least one, let me pick one and denote it by $g$". (3) If a node does not split, it does not have a successor, how are you going to continue constructing the path?

Comment: My definition of finitely splitting tree says: each node has finitely many immediate successors and each node has at least one immediate successor.

Comment: Well, hence why I qualified that paragraph with the fact that the definitions may vary. You didn't specify yours, and I didn't know if that was something you had taken into account or not. (Case in point, if the set of successors of a node is empty, it is still finite.)

Comment: Okay, great! One question: Is the choice function $g$ that selects a successor of $x_0$ the same as the one that selects a successor of $x_1=g(x_0)$, or you make use of AC in every step of the recursive definition of the branch?

Comment: The goal of AC is to be used as an oracle of some sort. It will guide you to building a branch. You give it a point, and it will choose a successor for you. But you only need one oracle.

Comment: But to ensure the existence of a choice function you need a priori a system of sets on which it acts, right? What would that system be?

Comment: Well, we are choosing from the successors of each node, so, perhaps the family of the successors of each of the nodes? Or, maybe, don't worry about it, and just take all the subsets of your tree (except the empty set, obviously).